# ATL COM DLL works with C# but not with C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, com, atl

EDIT:  I have included a link to the code for my ATL COM dll, the test application and my original C# dll.  As this is a complex project it might be the easiest solution.  I am pretty desperate as I have not been able to find a solution myself.
Here is the link, if anyone wants to take a look:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3ehFEncKJH7ZDgxMGI1YjgtZTE2MS00ZTBkLWI2NzgtYzVhZjUxOWEzZGI0

I created a dll using ATL and was trying to get it to work with a test program I was given.  I do not want to change the manner in which it accesses the dll as this is fixed.  I based the dll on a previous C# version and tried to keep the ProgIDs and UUIDs the same.

I have been having problems with a buffer overrun when I try to use any of the methods.  However I have run into another problem and I have no idea why it is occurring.  In order to make sure my dll was working I added a sleep statement to one of the methods.  When I call this method from my test program, written in unmanaged c++, the sleep function does not appear to work.  However, if I create a C# application and add my dll as a reference and call the method it does work.  Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Edit:
I thought I should include some more details about how it was being used.  The test c++ application creates and instance of the object like this:

```
IUserIDAPtr m_pUserIDA; 
::CoInitialize(m_pUserIDA);
m_pUserIDA.CreateInstance(_T("Analyst_UserIDA.UserIDAObject"));

if (m_pUserIDA != NULL)
{
    cout << "Aww yeah, that point isn't null" << endl;
    m_pUserIDA->AddRef();


    HRESULT result = m_pUserIDA->OnInitIDA();
```

right now the sleep function is in OnInitIDA.

When using C# I added a reference to the DLL and did this:

```
        UserIDAObject IDAObject = new UserIDAObject();
        IDAObject.OnInitIDA();
        short minCharge = 0;
        short maxCharge = 0;
        bool doChargeState = false;
        IDAObject.GetChargeStateParam(ref minCharge, ref maxCharge, ref doChargeState);
```

When I try to use GetChargeStatParam in the c++ application I get a buffer overrun but this does not happen in the C# version.  But I digress...
In this case the C# application sleeps for 10 seconds.

I just do not know where to even begin looking in order to figure out why it does not work.

EDIT:  This is the interface that is defined in the dll:

```
STDMETHOD(GetSwitchCriteria)(DOUBLE* intensity, DOUBLE* minMass, DOUBLE* maxMass, BOOL* selectIntensity, LONG* numOfDepCycles);
STDMETHOD(GetChargeStateParam)(SHORT* minCharge, SHORT* maxCharge, BOOL* doChargeState);
STDMETHOD(GetInclusionList)(DOUBLE* intensity, DOUBLE* theList, SHORT* numOfItems);
STDMETHOD(GetExclusionList)(LONG* exRTWindow, DOUBLE* theMassList, LONG* theRTList, SHORT* numOfItems);
STDMETHOD(GetOtherCriteria)(LONG* smartFilterTime, DOUBLE* isoExclusionWin, DOUBLE* massTolerance, BOOL* isPPM);
STDMETHOD(GetIsotopeMatchParam)(DOUBLE* theMassList, DOUBLE* theAbundanceList, DOUBLE* abTolerance, DOUBLE* maTolerance);
STDMETHOD(OnInitIDA)(void);
STDMETHOD(OnScreenSurveySpec)(void);
STDMETHOD(OnPrepareNextScan)(DOUBLE* selectedMasses, DOUBLE* selectedIntensities, LONG* selectedCharges, LONG itemCount);
```

this is the implementation of OnInitIDA

```
STDMETHODIMP CUserIDA::OnInitIDA(void)
{
// TODO: Add your implementation code here
Sleep(5000);
return S_OK;
}
```

Should I be concerned about how the UserIDA is defined in my dll?  My previous C# dll that had the same methods worked fine with this test application.

**EDIT:**
Strangely enough I have found some rather strange behaviour that might give someone an idea though it puzzles me.  I used the "Step Into" feature of VS2008 and found that when OnInitIDA is called it actually steps into another method GetInclusionList.  If I put some code in this method it gets run.  I also imagine this kind of behavior could cause a buffer overrun though I am not sure why this is actually happening.

Comment: You don't need to `AddRef` the pointer you got from `CreateInstance`.

Comment: Based on your edit I'd say your VTABLE is messed up. Most likely cause is a differing deinfition of the IDAObject interface on the C++ vs C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. You might want to post the code for OnInitIDA.

You do have a bug that may or may not be related:

Don't pass anything to `CoInitialize`. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> Parameters
>
> ```
> pvReserved [in, optional]
> ```
>
> This parameter is reserved and must be NULL.

Comment: I can look into that, I did not create the original test application so those mistakes are not my doing but I am still fairly new to windows programming and would not have caught them.  I will post some of the code.  But right now OnInitIDA is basically empty, just a single call to Sleep.

Comment: I did try changing that but it just resulted in a buffer overrun each time I ran it.  I should note that when I created a C# version of this dll the test app worked fine.  My goal with this ATL project was to exactly duplicate the dll and create a com dll that could be called by the same code.

Comment: Can you even hit a break point at your sleep statement. Based on what you've presented so far it sounds like something wrong with your project. Is it an ATL exe created with the wizard?

Comment: I tried entering a breakpoint before and it never seemed to hit it.  I will try again however.  It was created with the wizard.  I have asked a number of related questions recently as I have encountered a number of issues, so much of the code is spread throughout these.

Comment: If you can't hit a break point in the atl dll there is something else going on not related to you code, but rather your project or environment. Make sure in the dll project that the Linker setting Register Output is set to yes and that a clean build doesn't show error MSB8011. If you are certain that your dll is registered correctly and still can't hit a breakpoint try putting ATLASSERT(false); in your init method. That should allow you to attach a debugger. Also make sure you are working with debug builds not release.